# Задать border для стрелки

Tags: css

Есть стрелка на css - http://jsfiddle.net/4a5zY/

```css
.big_tooltip_narrow_c {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="big_tooltip_narrow_c"></div>
```

Как задать ей например черный бордер? Всю голову уже сломал, не могу найти решение.

Comment: @Павел Азанов, не нужно переделывать мой,комментарий в ответ, тем более в такой стрёмный. Я сам в состоянии решить, что я считаю комментарием а что ответом, к тому-же вы зачем-то удалили комментарий с объяснением.

Comment: @eicto, идея с наложением стрелки довольно идеальна. Воспользовался, всё отлично. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я пометил его :)

Comment: @eicto: Комментарий в ответ я передалал так как Вы дали готовое решение вопроса.

Comment: @Павел Азанов, я просто не приветствую ответы в в виде просто ссылок. Не нужно трогать мои комментарии в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По честному никак, можно сделать svg с base64, либо подложить одну стрелку под другую используя :before или :after [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/4a5zY/1/)

Comment: @eicto, готово :) спасибо!